# Error 1813 attempting to attach .mdf to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Running as admin.

- Right click `Databases -> Attach`, click `Add`
- Browse to directory containing `.mdf` files (NO FILES SHOWN)
- Manually type in file name -> Click "OK" (Message: "Not Found")
- Click OK
- Failure (SQL Server, Error: 1813)

To the best of my knowledge, the files exist, the permissions are correct, and there has been no reason for corruption (unexpected power outage, hard disk failure, etc.)

Please assist with resolving this, so I can use my database again!

Thank you!

P.S.

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio       11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)       6.2.9200.16384
Microsoft MSXML                               3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                   9.10.9200.16721
Microsoft .NET Framework                      4.0.30319.18051
Operating System                              6.2.9200
```

Comment: You are running as admin? Does the user running DB Engine service has access to that folder?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Thanks... I had a feeling this was a permissions. This is going to be a nightmare, because I don't have permission to change the permissions *facedesk*

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question, how about some constructive criticism on what you think would make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @NenadZivkovic for pointing me in the right direction.

The simple answer is that the user running the DB engine service did not have permission to access the folder.

The more complicated answer is that the permissions were FUBAR, and the actual permissions were not being displayed correctly in various locations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when attaching mdf file. I had to run as an administrator when opening the Mgt Studio, then extracted the mdf file...remove the log file...select the mdf file section and then click ok.

Answer (score 0):

it is either persmissions of the data-folder where mdf-file is or mdf-file is in read only mode.